# PCIe sound card not detected by mainboard / Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, motherboard, pci-express, sound-card

I'm using the following hardware setup:

- RyZen 2700
- 2x 32Gb DDR4
- Gigabyte B450 AORUS PRO https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-PRO-rev-10
- Gigabyte RTX2070 AORUS
- 6 SATA Devices
- PowerColor Devil HDX https://www.powercolor.com/product?id=1497250887
- 700W PSU

First time installing the Devil HDX Sound Card on mainboard it works superb. After some reboots it gets lost and Windows 10 Professional is not able to detect the hardware. Sometimes changing the PCIe port solves the issue for some time untill Windows looses the card again.

Did anyone have the same issues and a good way to solve?

Comment: I would start by updating the UEFI.

Comment: Did that. Now on "F40" from May 16th 2019. No change in PCIe sound card detection behaviour. Will have to check if switching PCIe to another slot will work getting the PCIe sound card discovered again.